# Are all Autoreceptors Downregulated by their Respective Endogenous Ligands?

Tags: neurotransmitter, receptor, autoreceptor

I know that the 5-HT<sub>1A</sub> and $\alpha$<sub>2</sub> adrenoreceptors receptors serve as autoreceptors for serotonin (5-HT) and norepinephrine respectively and are down-regulated by repeat exposure to their respective ligands, it's believed that this is likely the cause for the therapeutic delay in the actions of antidepressants that target the serotonergic and noradrenergic systems.  My question is this: "Is this the case for all autoreceptors? Are all autoreceptors down-regulated by the actions of their respective ligands?"

Answer (score 1):

Autoreceptors - are receptors of the presynaptic terminal.

α2 adrenoreceptors receptors are down-regulated due to repeated exposure.

> [Pharmacodynamic tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_tolerance) begins when the cellular response to a substance is reduced with repeated use. A common cause of pharmacodynamic tolerance is high concentrations of a substance constantly binding with the receptor, desensitizing it through constant interaction

This is a common occurrence - not just for autoreceptors but receptors in general.

But for your interest [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/590344/) is one for dopamine autoreceptors (Pay-wall).